# Looping result during parsing list

Tags: list, recursion, prolog

I'd like to parsing liste of dozens upper and lower atoms to achieve list of lists

**Example**

```
List = ['F1',a,'F2',a,b,'F3',a,b,c,...]
```

**Expected Result**

```
List_F =[['F1',a],['F2',a,b],['F3',a,b,c]|...]
```

I have two predicates `is_lower/1` and `is_upper/1` which return true if the current atom is lower (resp. upper),
at this stage I succeeded to do this predicate but with little `error` which the result is relooped

**Code**

```
get_functors([],[]).
get_functors([X,Y|Xs],[[X]|Facts]) :-         is_lower(X),is_upper(Y),
                                                   get_functors(Xs,Facts),!. 


get_functors([X,Y|Xs],[[X,Y|Fact]|Facts])     :-      is_lower(X),is_lower(Y),
                                                    get_functors(Xs,[Fact|Facts]).

get_functors([X,Y|Xs],[[X|Fact]|Facts])   :-      is_upper(X),is_lower(Y),
                                                    get_functors(Xs,[Fact|Facts]).
```

**Test**

```
| ?- get_functors(['F1',a,b,'F2',c,d],L).
L = [['F1',a,b],['F2',c,d]] ? ;
L = [['F1',a],[b],['F2',c,d]] ? ;
L = [['F1',a,b,'F2',c,d]] ? ;
L = [['F1',a,b,'F2',c],[d]] ? ;
L = [['F1',a,b,'F2',c,d]] ? ;
L = [['F1',a,b,'F2'],[c,d]] ? ;
L = [['F1',a,b,'F2'],[c],[d]] ? 
yes
```

I think that is because the **`Cut "!"`**, but I don't know where I shoud put it

if there are some improvements to this predicate plz suggest them

Answer (score 1):

In the solution you show, if you find you're trying to figure out where to put a cut to trim out incorrect answers, then the logic is not correct somewhere since it allows invalid solutions.

This would make a good problem for a DCG (definite clause grammar) solution, and is more easily conceptualized and solved this way:

```
get_functors(List, Functors) :-
    phrase(functor_list(Functors), List).

% An empty functor list results from an empty input
% A functor list [F|T] results from seeing a term F follow by a functor list, T

functor_list([]) --> [].
functor_list([F|T]) --> term(F), functor_list(T).

% A term [F|A] is an upper case atom followed by a list of lower case atoms

term([F|A]) --> [F], { is_upper(F) }, lc_atoms(A).

% Recognize a list of lower case atoms 

lc_atoms([]) --> [].
lc_atoms([H|T]) --> [H], { is_lower(H) }, lc_atoms(T).

% Some simple definitions of is_upper and is_lower

is_upper(S) :-
    atom_codes(S, [X|_]),
    X =< 90, X >= 65.

is_lower(S) :-
    \+ is_upper(S).
```

I threw this together kind of quickly, so there may still be some niggles in it, and it leaves a choice point, but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Here's a sample query:

```
| ?-  get_functors(['F1',a,'F2',a,b,'F3',a,b,c], L).

L = [['F1',a],['F2',a,b],['F3',a,b,c]] ? a

(1 ms) no
```

---

You can use `listing` in GNU or SWI Prolog to see the canonical predicate form of the DCG:

```
functor_list([], A, A).
functor_list([A|B], C, D) :-
        term(A, C, E),
        functor_list(B, E, D).

term([A|B], [A|C], D) :-
        is_upper(A),
        lc_atoms(B, C, D).

lc_atoms([], A, A).
lc_atoms([A|B], [A|C], D) :-
        is_lower(A),
        lc_atoms(B, C, D).

is_upper(A) :-
        atom_codes(A, [B|_]),
        B =< 90,
        B >= 65.

is_lower(A) :-
        \+ is_upper(A).
```

This would be called directly by:

```
get_functors(List, Functors) :-
    functor_list(Functors, List, []).
```

Comment: thnx, but DCG is'it integrated in SICStus-prolog and  is'it capable to prase file of tweets ?

Comment: @AnsPiter the DCG can be translated into predicates. If you have GNU Prolog or SWI Prolog you can load it in, then do `listing` which will show you the canonical predicate form. You would call `functor_list(L, ['F1',a,'F2',a,b,'F3',a,b,c], []).` for example to execute.

Comment: @AnsPeter although the cut avoids your code yielding invalid solutions, it's still not what I would consider to be a good use of the cut per my comments in my answer. BTW, from what I've gleaned online (I didn't research it deeply), there seems to be a DCG capability available for SICStus Prolog, described in the [SICStus Prolog Manual - DCG](https://books.google.com/books?id=dZimAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA186&lpg=PA186&dq=sicstus+prolog+dcg&source=bl&ots=Azs7oBgxJ6&sig=y2Sp7GYeRG2N9vfdZhI4_qTxqqw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiZ5Ymr5czKAhVINT4KHfiLC0wQ6AEIOjAF#v=onepage&q=sicstus%20prolog%20dcg&f=false).